# github c# implementation to consume dropbox api

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/saguiitay/DropboxRestAPI). Just curious where do I get ClientId, ClientSecret, and especially RedirectUri from as required in this code:

```
var options = new Options
{
    ClientId = "...",
    ClientSecret = "...",
    RedirectUri = "..."
};
```

I am currently using App key and App secret provided via my dropbox account for ClientId and ClientSecret. Is this correct? Where do I obtain RedirectUri? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the context of the Dropbox API, the `ClientId` is your app key, and the `ClientSecret` is your app secret.

Your `RedirectUri` should be whatever URL you want the user redirected back to after the OAuth 2 app authorization flow where they go to dropbox.com to authorize your app to link to their account. This address is chosen by you, e.g., to go to a particular page on your web app, and needs to be registered for your app on the Dropbox App Console:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps

Make sure the `RedirectUri` you use in your code is exactly the same as what you register there.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look into this. Just curious, I just want to use the api within a windows service. Should I just use a fake address?

Comment: It depends specifically on how you're implementing the authorization flow, but I'm unfortunately not familiar with this library in particular. Generally you shouldn't use a _fake_ address, but you may want to use a static address you control.

Comment: Thanks. In my scenario the authentication is done by a program rather than a human - so having an authentication web address just does not make sense - I guess I will just try a fake address. Still confused ...